# Updated to OpenSSH 8.1 on Ubuntu 19.10 But shows Older Version while scanning from SecurityMetrics

Tags: security, digital-ocean, openssh

I manually upgraded **OpenSSH 8.1p1 from 7.7 on Ubuntu 19.10**, few days ago. While checking the version from server it shows latest i.e `8.1p1`.

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.1p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019
```

But scanning the port from third party services i.e [Security Metrics](https://www.securitymetrics.com/). It shows the older version instead. Here's the screenshot.
[image]

Did i miss something or security metrics ?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [ubuntu.se], [unix.se], [sf], or [su].